# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows()

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I am requesting help with my PHP. I checked the code through and I couldn't spot any errors in it.

I'm not that great with PHP, and I hope any of you could help.

It should return either false or true but, I get this error

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows()`

Here is my code:

`$mysqli` is my mysqli database connector.

```
$email = $_SESSION["email"];

function isbanned($email){
    global $mysqli;
    if($mysqli->num_rows("SELECT * FROM `user_bans` WHERE `banned_id` = '".$email."' LIMIT 1") > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

isbanned($email);
```

That's all my code for the banned script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`->num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) isn't a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how that function is used. First you execute your query and *then* you check to see how many rows were returned from the returned result object:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_bans` WHERE `banned_id` = '".$email."' LIMIT 1");
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: technically it's a property and not a function. just sayin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_bans` WHERE `banned_id` = '".$email."' LIMIT 1")->num_rows > 0)
```

Should do it. Call ->query first, and then get the variable ->num_rows from the result object