# mysql_num_rows in abantecart

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a new screen in abantecart and i need to chaeck whether a userid is present in the database or not.If it is already there i need to update or else i have to insert .For this im using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->db->table("payment_details") . "  WHERE user_id='" . $userid . "'";
$result = $this->db->query( $sql );

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
```

but here, this if condition always returns false and insert query is executed in else.

How can i use `mysql_num_rows` in abantecart.

Comment: Can you share a more complete snippet please?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `if ($result->num_rows() > 0)` to get true or false for making your decision.

For more reference check [Generating Query Results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) in CodeIgniter.

Alternatively also `if ($result->num_rows > 0)`  can be used. Checkout the solution is given [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722548/2627842) though thats `$mysqli` object. This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/arifulhb/4410c14d799f96815e1e) in my github as example of `num_rows` implementation.

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::num_rows()

Answer (score 1):

> $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->db->table("payment_details") . "  WHERE user_id='" . $userid . "'");

```
             if($sql->num_rows >0){
```

I got it correct, by using like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...this logic may helps you....work with this $this->db->count_all_results();

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->db->table("payment_details") . "  WHERE user_id='" .       $userid . "'";

$result = $this->db->query( $sql );
//work with this $this->db->count_all_results();
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
{
//Write update query
}
else {
//Write Insert query
}
```

Comment: The same error im getting..."Call to undefined method ADB::count_all_results()"